# how to add search criteria for a range of values in msaccess 2003

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am using the code below to filter a query to return values entered in search fields on a form.

how can I modify the code, to allow my user to search for records with values greater than or less than a number in the search field.

for example the user enters 60 as the [OD] - I want the code to return records with an [OD] between 55 and 65 ([60] +/- 5).

since i'm using the addtowhere function below, I don't know how to modify this code.

can anyone help?

```
Public Sub cmdSearch_Click()

'  Create a WHERE clause using search criteria entered by user and
'  set RecordSource property of SEARCH QUOTE SUBform.
If Me.[Goodsinsub].Form.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then Me.Goodsinsub.Form.Command95.Visible = False Else Me.Goodsinsub.Form.Command95.Visible = True
Dim MySQL As String, MyCriteria As String, myrecordsource As String
Dim ArgCount As Integer
Dim tmp As Variant
Dim mycontrol As Control

'  Initialize argument count.
ArgCount = 0

'  Initialize SELECT statement.
MySQL = "SELECT * FROM [qry_tubes out] WHERE"
MyCriteria = ""

'  Use values entered in text boxes in form header to create criteria for WHERE clause.
AddToWhere [Combo30], "[product]", MyCriteria, ArgCount
AddToWhere [OD], "[OD]", MyCriteria, ArgCount
AddToWhere [ID], "[ID]", MyCriteria, ArgCount
AddToWhere [LG], "[LG]", MyCriteria, ArgCount

'  If no criterion specifed, return all records.
If MyCriteria = "" Then
    MyCriteria = "True"
End If

'  Create SELECT statement.
myrecordsource = MySQL & MyCriteria

'  Set RecordSource property of Find Customers Subform.
Me![Goodsinsub].Form.RecordSource = myrecordsource

'  If no records match criteria, display message.
'  Move focus to Clear button.
If Me![Goodsinsub].Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
tmp = EnableControls("detail", True)
MsgBox "No records found"
Else
    '  Enable control in detail section.
    tmp = EnableControls("Detail", True)
    '  Move insertion point to Find Customers Subform.
    Me![Goodsinsub].Visible = True


End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "WHERE [OD] BETWEEN (" & ArgCount - 5 & " AND " & ArgCount + 5 & ")"

Comment: Hi Igor, can you explain where to add this in to the above code, I've tried on the addtowhere [OD],"[OD]" ..... line, but it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

> the user enters 60 as the [OD] - I want the code to return records
>   with an [OD] between 55 and 65 ([60] +/- 5).

You can use *Abs* for this:

```
Where Abs([Enter OD] - [OD]) <= 5
```

Comment: hi Gustav, how do i introduce this into the code above?

Comment: You may have to modify your `AddToWhere` function to take care of that.